# Why is only 3 dots showing and not the full text?

Tags: javafx, radio-button, hbox

When I run the following code the radio button appears but instead of the text showing next to the button there is only 3 three little dots '...'. Why is that please?

```
    RadioButton rd= new RadioButton("Hello");
    rd.setPrefSize(500, 500)
    HBox hB = new HBox();   
    myDialog.getDialogPane().getChildren().add(hB);
    hB.getChildren().add(rd);
    hB.setPrefSize(500, 500);
    hB.setLayoutX(100);
    hB.setLayoutY(200);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to have a bigger frame. Maybe you should try a bit lower size.**

Java can't show the text you want to put there. *This problem applies to everyone.*